# Combinations Integer Solutions to Inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How do I find the number of integer valued solutions to the following?

\begin{equation} x_1 + x_2 + x_3 <  27 \text{ for all }x_i > 0\end{equation}

\begin{equation} x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =  27 \text{ for all }x_i > 0 , x_2 \ge5\end{equation}

Is there a concrete formula I can follow in order to solve similar problems?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There are just as many of these as there are positive integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=17$. I expect you know the Stars and Bars approach (please see Wikipedia) to the second problem.

**Added:** The question has changed since I answered it: The $17$ became $27$, and a sand a second equation was added.

The change from $17$ to $27$ in the inequality changes virtually nothing: the $17$ gets replaced by $27$.

For the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=27$, with the condition $x_i \gt 0$, $x_2\ge 5$, give $4$ candies to Kid $2$. Then we need to distribute $23$ candies among $3$ kids, at least one to each kid. This is straight Stars and Bars.

Comment: sorry I meant 27, not 17